# How does Fragment Transaction work with animations?

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I am having a really annoying situation with Fragment Transaction.

In my activity there is a fragment that must appears with a slide up animation:

```
public void showConnectedToWifiCard(String ssid) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("SSID", ssid);

    ConnectedToWifiCardFragmentImpl fm =  new ConnectedToWifiCardFragmentImpl();
    fm.setArguments(bundle);

    // Begin the transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // Replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
    //ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, R.anim.slide_down_anim);

    //ft.hide(fm);
    if (ft == null){
        ft.add(R.id.main_small_card, fm);
    }else{
        ft.replace(R.id.main_small_card, fm);
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

I supposed that Fragment Transaction would create the fragment (or replace) right after the animation, but, the result is that:

- Fragment appears in the activity
- Fragment disappears
- Fragment starts the animation.

I have tried to set invisible/visible the fragment but the result doesn't change.

How can I solve this "blink"?

Comment: Check out this question, he apparently manage to do it without problems (with the java code in the response) : http://goo.gl/yYHsDp Try to do it like him and using the same xml file (I now it is left to right and not pull up animation, but it is to test), and keep me informed if it work or not.

Answer (score 2):

For making animation when replacing Fragment, you can use this code:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            //set customize animation here
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out,
                    R.anim.slide_right_in, R.anim.slide_right_out);

            ExampleFragment fragment = ExampleFragment.getInstance();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Please see my blog post for more details:
http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/05/replacing-fragment-and-adding-layouts.html
Hope this help! :D

Comment: As you can see in my code I made exactly the same as you do (except of adding the fragment to backstack, because there is no need). The problem persist with this code.

Comment: Hmm...I think you must use `setCustomAnimation(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)` instead of `setCustomAnimation(arg1, arg2)`!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather attach view element to the fragment and use invalidate() than replace fragment everytime when the fragment is created. Or you could use animation library which is introduced in android DOC.

Answer (score 0):

I recoded the animations:

Slide_up.xml

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="1000"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

slide_down.xml

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="-1000"
    android:duration="1500"/>
```